# Can I link a Node.js C++ extension against Node's internal OpenSSL implementation?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I have a Node extension written in C++ that needs to link against OpenSSL. I also see that Node has a [TLS Module](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html) That is implemented using OpenSSL. Can I link my extension against the Node copy of OpenSSL in my binding.gyp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this exact scenario is covered in the [node-gyp documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/wiki/Linking-to-OpenSSL). Basically, there are directories with OpenSSL headers that are included with the Node.js source distribution and that can be added to the node-gyp include path list. On Linux, actual linking is unnecessary because the symbols will be made available to the extension by the Node runtime when it is loaded.

On Windows, this does not work, and the extension needs to explicitly compile and link against an external copy of OpenSSL that is installed separately.